# sequence.nextval function in named query hibernate 4

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Is there a way to make sql do the operation my_sequence.nextval from hibernate @NamedQuery??
I tried something like this @NamedQuery(name="",query=" select nextval('schema.my_sequence')" ) and its many alternatives.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried `select my_sequence.nextval from dual`?

Comment: yes, it doesn't work in hql, I did not find a way to do it with hql so i had to do it by common sql query. but still could do with knowing how to do the same in hql